# Programmatically Create Unicode?

Tags: scala, unicode

Given a hex `String`, how can I programmatically create a Unicode `String`?

Example:

`def f(x: String): String = s"\u$s"`

fails to compile:

```
scala> def f(x: String): String = s"\u$s"
<console>:1: error: error in unicode escape
       def f(x: String): String = s"\u$s"
                                      ^
```

I tried the following, but it failed:

```
scala> def f(x: String): String = "\\u" + x
f: (x: String)String

scala> f("0021")
res19: String = \u0021

scala> "\u0021"
res20: String = !

scala> res19 == res20
res21: Boolean = false
```

Comment: do any of the posts below answer your question? If so, please accept one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt defer to the Java libs:

```
scala> def hexStrToChar(hex: String): Char = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16).toChar
hexStrToChar: (hex: String)Char

scala> hexStrToChar("0021")
res1: Char = !
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether there's a way to call into the exact code the compiler is using, but doing it yourself seems simple enough.

Split the string into groups of 4 and use `Integer.parseInt` to get a code point, then convert it to a character.

```
scala> "27640021".grouped(4).map(Integer.parseInt(_, 16).toChar).mkString
res1: String = ❤!
```